# SQL Case column is null redefine selectors

Tags: sql, join, left-join

i want to create an SQL select statement that will JOIN a few tables and yeidl results. Essentially i have two tables that are independent of one another. One table contains users (which is assumed to have the most up to date and correct information) and i have a placed holder table called players. The placeholder table has a column labelled userID which is set as NULL. when a user is recognized as a player then the NULL value for userID is replaced by the user's unique id.

This cases me to want to use SQL to test if userID is NULL. i have written the following statement which does not work

```
SELECT 
    teams.*, players.number, players.position,  players.userId, 
CASE WHEN players.userId IS NULL THEN players.id ELSE userPlayer.id END AS playerId,
CASE WHEN players.userId IS NULL THEN players.firstName ELSE userPlayer.firstName END AS firstName,
CASE WHEN players.userId IS NULL THEN players.lastName ELSE userPlayer.lastName END AS lastName,
CASE WHEN players.userId IS NULL THEN players.email ELSE userPlayer.email END AS email 

FROM teams 
LEFT JOIN players ON players.teamId = teams.id 
LEFT JOIN users AS userPlayer ON userPlayer.id= players.userId 

WHERE teams.id = (:t)
```

This seems very inefficient. Is there a better way?

thanks

Comment: Do you only want to return results where the `Player` has a corresponding `User`? Or, do you want to return *all* players, and sometimes `userId` will be `NULL` and sometimes it won't?

Comment: i want to record the user when the player has a corresponding user

Comment: The above statement does work as right now it cycles through a listing of players on the team

Comment: Is there some reason why you're not using `COALESCE`, instead of `CASE WHEN...  IS NULL...`?

Comment: should i replace CASE WHEN WITH COALESCE(players.userId, userPlayer.xxxx) ?

Comment: what about an if null?

Comment: i was hoping that i could do something like ..  if x is null then {BULK ADJUSTMENT} ELSE {SOMETHING ELSE}

Comment: @bushbrigade your last comment is an a-ha moment.

Comment: @bushbrigade if `players.userId` is `NULL` is it safe to say that `userPlayer.Id`, `userPlayer.firstName`, `userPlayer.lastName`, etc are also `NULL`?

Comment: No the userPlayer table will always have values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, `userPlayer.id` is never different from `players.userId` (either both are something, or both are null), so you can dispense with that expression.

Also, use `coalesce()` in preference to `case when x is null` for clarity and brevity:

```
SELECT
    teams.*, players.number, players.position, 
    players.userId AS playerId,
    COALESCE(userPlayer.firstName, players.firstName) AS firstName,
    COALESCE(userPlayer.lastName, players.lastName) AS lastName,
    COALESCE(userPlayer.email, players.email) AS email 
FROM teams 
LEFT JOIN players ON players.teamId = teams.id 
LEFT JOIN users AS userPlayer ON userPlayer.id = players.userId 
WHERE teams.id = (:t)
```

Comment: This statement is not true "To begin with, userPlayer.id is never different from players.userId" AS players.userId can be NULL while userPlayer.id will always be a unique alphanumeric value

Comment: @bushbrigade but due to the join condition, if player.userId is null there will be no join to users, so the left join will return nulls for all users columns. Thus, my answer stands true: for any given row, either player.userId and users.id have the same (non-null) value, or they are both null.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view where you can comfortably select teams by their id. In this case it is possible to optimize, because if players.userId is null then all values of user are null (because of left join). So you could create a union, if you have a lot of null entries it could be beneficial:

```
SELECT
   teams.*, players.number, players.position, players.userId AS playerId,
   players.firstName, players.lastName, players.email
FROM
   teams LEFT JOIN players ON players.teamId = teams.id
WHERE
   players.userId IS NULL OR
   NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id = players.userId)

UNION

SELECT
   teams.*, players.number, players.position, players.userId AS playerId,
   COALESCE(userPlayer.firstName, players.firstName) AS firstName,
   COALESCE(userPlayer.lastName, players.lastName) AS lastName,
   COALESCE(userPlayer.email, players.email) AS email
FROM
   teams
   INNER JOIN players ON players.teamId = teams.id 
   INNER JOIN users AS userPlayer ON userPlayer.id = players.userId
```

Answer (score 0):

If your "players.userId" the PK, you can try this:

```
SELECT 
    teams.*, players.number, players.position,  players.userId, 
ISNULL(players.id, userPlayer.id) AS playerId,
ISNULL(players.firstName, userPlayer.firstName) AS firstName,
ISNULL(players.lastName, userPlayer.lastName) AS lastName,
ISNULL(players.email, userPlayer.email) AS email 

FROM teams 
LEFT JOIN players ON players.teamId = teams.id 
LEFT JOIN users AS userPlayer ON userPlayer.id= players.userId 

WHERE teams.id = (:t)
```